# Auto install dependencies when installing rpm package

Tags: dependencies, installation, rpm

I'm new on Centos and i would like to know how to install an rpm package with all it dependencies.

Example : [deepin-screenshot](http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/29/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/d/deepin-screenshot-4.0.10.4-4.fc29.x86_64.rpm)

When i try to install it with :

```
rpm -Uvh deepin-screenshot-4.0.10.4-4.fc29.x86_64.rpm
```

i have a dependency error :

```
attention : deepin-screenshot-4.0.10.4-4.fc29.x86_64.rpm: Entête V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, clé ID 429476b4: NOKEY
erreur : Dépendances requises:
    libQt5Core.so.5(Qt_5.11)(64bit) est nécessaire pour deepin-screenshot-4.0.10.4-4.fc29.x86_64
    libdtkcore.so.2()(64bit) est nécessaire pour deepin-screenshot-4.0.10.4-4.fc29.x86_64
    libdtkwidget.so.2()(64bit) est nécessaire pour deepin-screenshot-4.0.10.4-4.fc29.x86_64
    libdtkwm.so.2()(64bit) est nécessaire pour deepin-screenshot-4.0.10.4-4.fc29.x86_64
```

Comment: Salut! Maybe [this article](https://www.ostechnix.com/download-rpm-package-dependencies-centos/) can help?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Joey but i had already tried this without success :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the yum install rpm_name.
sudo yum install deepin-screenshot-4.0.10.4-4.fc29.x86_64.rpm

The rpm command does not download the dependencies from the internet, yum does.

Moreover, Uvh parameter in your command stands for uninstall, verbose, hash.
So, you are trying to uninstall the RPM with your mentioned command instead of installing it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install a Fedora 29 package (the `fc29` suffix) on CentOS. You need to find a CentOS version of the RPM you're installing, or rebuild it from source.

After that, you could use `yum` to handle dependency traching.